# groovy grape grab not using proxy settings

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

I'm running Groovy v2.4.5 behind a firewall and I have a local cntlm proxy.
FYI, when I use grab on open networks, it works.

I've tried running my script this way:

`groovy  -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Divy.message.logger.level=3 try_grape_grab.groovy`

And settings those same properties in JAVA_OPTS but groovy doesn't seem to use them, I just see that the download hangs.

`export JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128"`

If I use a browser (with proxy settings) I can access the pom that grab is trying to download, so the web proxy is not blocking access to those files either.

Note - I've tried the same with the grape command as well but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your proxy require authentication?

Comment: Actually, the corporate one does,  hence I have a local cntlm proxy that proxies my local Linux connections to the Internet via that corporate proxy since they can't do Windows NTLM auth. I can run a browser on my Linux system and it reaches the Internet via the local cntlm proxy.

Comment: You could try to add the corresponding https settings, even though the groovy docs don't mention them? `The https (http over SSL) protocol handler has its own set of properties` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by [andi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6014014/andi) was the key - I needed to proxy HTTPS also (doh!). It worked once I changed how I ran the script to:

`groovy  -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Divy.message.logger.level=3 try_grape_grab.groovy`

Thanks Andi!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `@GrabConfig` to do this.  Inside your `try_grape_grab.groovy`:

```
@Grapes([
  @Grab('some:thing:1.0'),
  @GrabConfig(systemProperties='httpProxy.host=127.0.0.1,httpProxy.port=3128')
])
...
```